# read csv in R, bad formatting?

Tags: r, csv

I've got the following csv-file:

```
"ID,""oldid"",""country"",""side_a"",""densdiff"
"10,32,""Afghanistan"",""Afghanistan"",""Various organizations"
```

During the exercises we got a few csv-files that where always formattet "clear" e.g.

```
"ID","oldid","country" ...
"10","32","Afghanistan" ...
```

I figured out, that the separator is a "," but it is sometimes in a string ("ID,"), sometimes there is no separator 
(looks like : 
    "intden"",""densdiff"""
so I don't know what to do with the last two quotes)

I didn't found a good website that explains a "mixed-csv-formatted" input for R.

Edit: Here is the complete header and the first line:

```
"ID,""oldid"",""country"",""side_a"",""side_b"",""cow"",""incompatibility"",""terr"",""begin"",""end"",""type"",""identity"",""radius"",""confarea"",""landarea"",""confland"",""rel_scope"",""distance"",""maxdist"",""mindist"",""disper"",""pop2000"",""resource"",""mountain"",""forest"",""border"",""mindisx"",""lnmndist"",""confarex"",""ln_abs_scope"",""ln_land_area"",""lnpop"",""lnconpro"",""duration"",""distx"",""location"",""mountx"",""frstx"",""lnmountx"",""lnfrstx"",""diamond"",""diadist"",""gold"",""golddist"",""oil"",""oildist"",""roadpave"",""roadtot"",""pavetot"",""paveland"",""roadland"",""disxsqr"",""mndisxsq"",""stabilit"",""rulelaw"",""nocorrup"",""lnd100km"",""pop100km"",""lnd100cr"",""pop100cr"",""landlock"",""ciffob95"",""coastden"",""intden"",""densdiff"""
```

And the next line:

```
"10,32,""Afghanistan"",""Afghanistan"",""Various organizations"",700,2,"""",1978,2000,3,1,400,500,652,77,77,122,522,0,0.509999990463257,27,0,66,3,1,1,0,500,6.21460819244385,6.4800443649292,3.29583692550659,0.959037899971008,23,122,4.80402088165283,66,3,4.18965482711792,1.0986123085022,0,NA,0,NA,0,NA,2.79999995231628,21,13.3333330154419,0.429447859525681,3.22085881233215,14884,1,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,1,NA,0,36,-36"
```

Edit 2:
After a lot of trubbleshooting I downloaded only the csv-file and it is clean now. I will do a comment after questioning my lecturer. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Try something like `read.csv(text = gsub('\\"', "", readLines("ex.csv")))` where `ex.csv` is your csv file.

Comment: That throws an error: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
I got this message before when I tried manually (search and replace) replace the quotes ;)

Comment: I don't know what R is capable of reading, but your CSV looks messed up to me. I'd recommend cleaning it up with some `awk` or `sed` filtering before feeding it to R.

Comment: Yeah, I asked the lecturer and he said the csv-file should be readable with R :-/ I do some research for awk and sed.

Comment: Try `data.table::fread("cat file | tr -d '\"'")` is on a unix-alike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"ID,""oldid"",""country"",""side_a"",""densdiff"  .."
"10,32,""Afghanistan"",""Afghanistan"",""Various organizations"  .."
```

This csv is written as the whole row being one field, and surrounded with quotes. Therefore the inner quotes are escaped with an extra quote.

So, it is in fact a csv file generated from an already well formatted csv file (or data), with the full rows now converted to a single field.

This should probably **be fixed at the source** first.

**To fix it afterwards**, the rows should be read in and parsed as one csv field. Then the contents of that parsed field (where all the extra quotes should be stripped by now)

```
10,32,"Afghanistan","Afghanistan","Various organizations"  ..
```

should again be treated and parsed as a full csv row.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this? You need the readr package for the read_lines function.

```
> x <- read_lines("data.csv") #Read the dirty quotes csv file

> x                           # Display contents
    [1] "\"ID,\"\"oldid\"\",\"\"country\"\",\"\"side_a\"\",\"\"densdiff\""           
    [2] "\"10,32,\"\"Afghanistan\"\",\"\"Afghanistan\"\",\"\"Various organizations\""

> x2 <- textConnection(gsub('"', "", x)) # Replace all " with null and create a connection object

> x3 <- read.csv(x2, header=TRUE) # Read the conn object as you would a regular file

> x3
      ID oldid     country      side_a              densdiff
    1 10    32 Afghanistan Afghanistan Various organizations
```

Comment: That should work but the csv-file is too bad messed up. I downloaded the lecturers zip-file and found the messed up csv. After that I searched the git-hub-branch of my lecturer and found the file as a clean formattet csv. I see the lecturer the next week, I will ask him why this csv-file is so messed up in the zip-file and comment my post.

Comment: Why can't you read the lines using base `readLines`? Your answer is basically what I already suggested in comments.

Comment: @Markus - see my answer as to why it is messed up. (in fact, it isn't as bad as it seems :)

Answer (score 1):

As David Arenburg suggested in comments, you should try something like this:

```
> read.csv(text = gsub("\"", "", readLines("file.csv")))
  ID oldid     country      side_a              densdiff
1 10    32 Afghanistan Afghanistan Various organizations
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct CSV should look something like:

```
12,13,"abc","def"
```

The following should clean it up, given that the format corresponds to you example throughout and you don't have any commas inside the strings:

```
cat my.csv | sed 's/,"/,/' | sed 's/","/,/g' | sed 's/^"//' > mynew.csv
```

Comment: I got the Error: unexpected symbol in "cat my.csv". I edited my post above and completed the first and second line.

Comment: I would say it doesn't work....
One of the purposes of the quote is to allow , in texts, e.g., `echo 12,13,\"abc2,\",\"def\" | sed 's/,"/,/' | sed 's/","/,/g' | sed 's/^"//'`
which gives  `12,13,abc2,,def"`

Comment: @Markus `sed`, `cat` & Co. are not inside R, it's supposed to be done to the CSV file outside of R, beforehand. They are tools usually installed on a Linux system.

Comment: @CAFEBABE right, if there are commas inside the text fields it won't work. It's a quick solution for a file that strictly adheres to the format shown in the first example.